# html/css list with coloured dot

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list in html.
I want to have a dot with a dark-red color (#A71316).
I tried it like this but now i got both a red dot and a default dot.
Does anyone know how to solve this?
my code is:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #A5A5A5;padding:20px;background-color:#D3D3D3;"><ul style="list-style:none;">
    <li style="color:#A71316;list-style:disc inside none;"><a style="font-size:14px;" href="/user">Log in</a></li>
    <li style="color:#A71316;list-style:disc inside none;"><a style="font-size:14px;" href="/doorleesartikelen">Magazine</a></li>
    <li style="color:#A71316;list-style:disc inside none;"><a style="font-size:14px;" href="/autoinbedrijf/magazine">Magazine archief</a></li>
    <li style="color:#A71316;list-style:disc inside none;"><a style="font-size:14px;" href="/content/kunt-u-goed-door-de-bocht-met-uw-collega">Nieuwsbrief</a></li>
    <li style="color:#A71316;list-style:disc inside none;"><a style="font-size:14px;" href="/actueel/actie/aantrekkelijke-voorraadselectie">Voorraad Selectie</a></li>
    <li style="color:#A71316;list-style:disc inside none;"><a style="font-size:14px;" href="http://www.groeneselectie.nl/" style="text-decoration:none;" class="ext">Groene Selectie</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/GXHbX/  Perhaps some other style from a css file is interfering? What browser are you checking in?

Comment: Do you use inline styles because you have to? If not, simplify all that in a class, much cleaner...